# unable to use javapackager command

Tags: javapackager

I am using ubuntu 16.04, and my java is in /usr/bin/java
and jdk is in /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64   . non of these had the javapackager inside.
I am not able to use javapackager command  and do not know how to configure it to use in command-line.
Can anyone help me? 
Thanks.

Comment: Could you please provide the command/s you are trying to execute and the output you get?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did not have the javapackager in $JAVA_HOME/bin and I noticed that openjdk does not come with javapackager and had to install oracle jdk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define your java path.

You can set your `JAVA_HOME` in `/etc/profile` as Petronilla Escarabajo suggests. But the preferred location for `JAVA_HOME` or any system variable is `/etc/environment`.

Open `/etc/environment` in any text editor like nano or gedit and add the following

```
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/open-jdk" (java path could be different)
```

Use source to load the variables, by running this command:

source /etc/environment
Then check the variable, by running this command:

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But as I said I did not have the javapackager in $JAVA_HOME/bin 
and I noticed that openjdk does not come with javapackager and had to install oracle jdk.

Comment: But your answer was helpful. And if you want you can mention my point in your answer for people who do not read the comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems `javapackager` comes with a package called `openjfx`,
so running `apt install openjfx` should make the tool available for you, among your other java tools.

```
$ apt-file search javapackager
openjfx: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javapackager
openjfx: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1/javapackager.1.gz
openjfx: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/man1/javapackager.1.gz
```